# Rails 6: Controller helper methods still in the /app/helpers folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

Can I still define helper methods in `/app/helpers/<controller_name>/<file_name>.rb` or do I have to use Concerns now?

And if I have written a helper-method where-ever the *cool place to put them in Rails 6 is now* by what command do I now make them available to the view according to the controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Rails 6 all helpers are included in the controllers by default](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) and accessible through `helpers`. This changed from previous Rails versions, it used to be each controller included a helper with the same name of the controller by default (and didn't need to access it's method through 'helpers')

Comment: Okay, and where would I have to place the `FormattedTimeHelper` module?

Comment: seems fine where you placed it, are you not able to access it?

Comment: Ah now it works. With `helper SessionsHelper` from the file `/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`. Thanks !